# A particle returns to the starting post after 10s. If the rate of change of velocity during the motion is constant in magnitude

Tags: kinematics

Then it’s location after 7 seconds will be the same as that after-?

Now my super-efficient and productive brain (#sarcasm) can figure out that it’s 3 seconds, since it has got a constant velocity and 10-7=3. But I doubt future questions like this will be that easy. Is there anyway to solve it ‘properly’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are given that the acceleration is constant.  The velocity is then a linear function of time and the position is quadratic.  The equation for the velocity and position when the acceleration is constant is 
$$v=v_0+at\\s=s_0+v_0t+\frac 12at^2$$
You should be able to derive these by integration.  $s_0$ is the position at $t=0$ and $v_0$ is the velocity at $t=0$.  We are given $s(10)=s(0)=s_0$.  By taking the derivative you can show that $v(5)=0$, so $v_0=-5a$ and plugging in you can find that your intuition is correct.

Comment: Yeah I am sorry. I basically thought of it as $\frac{dv}{dt}=K$ so assumed (wrongly) that velocity was constant.